# Powershell script to run parallel on different server to perform cleanup

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I want to perform disk cleanup on 500 VDIs using below script and create a proper report with VDI status(online or offline) and disk space detail using below script .But here Iam not using for each loop as I want to run cleanup parallel on VDIs .If any VDI is offline or winRM not enabled the script will throw error for that VDIs ,I want to catch those VDI and put in report if they are offline or any other winrm error .I can get disk space detail for online VDI but how to get offline or error VDI status in report ???????

```
$AllVDI = get-content "list for500 vDI "
$Space= Invoke-Command -ComputerName $AllVDI  -ScriptBlock {
                                Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Temp\*"  -Recurse -Force 
                               Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"
}
$Space|select systemname,drive,freespace|export.csv "C:\report"
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is running elements of powershell as jobs - https://ss64.com/ps/start-job.html , You would create jobs to invoke commands on the multiple servers. Some more info here about running jobs in parallell - https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-multithreading/#Parallel_Execution_with_PSJobs

Comment: Its already creating session on multiple servers ,but when some servers are unreachable it will fail and throw error in powershell console . I want to catch those servers and print their status as offline into the report which i am extracting or in any other text file .Here Iam not using for each loop as its taking so long time

Answer (score 0):

Hi Actually I am using PowerShell 5.1 so cannot use foreach-object -Parallel

```
invoke-command -computername srv1,srv2,srv3 -scriptblock {get-process}
```

This command by default will run in parallel .I just wanted proper report with offline and online servers with disk space detail . I got my issue resolved from Microsoft QnA ..Just FYI the below link the way I m expecting .

Thank you for your help indeed ...appreciated

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/230721/powershelll-script-to-get-server-status-and-disk-s.html?childToView=231124#answer-231124